The measure of a set of continued fractions.
What would be the measure of the set of continued fractions which only contain 1 or 2 in the denominator, including infinite fractions? If I understand measure correctly, the set of continued fractions with only 1 (or any other number) is 0, since it's a countable list. However, with 2 different numbers, the list becomes uncountable, by a diagonalization argument. I have very little experience with measure theory, but the question seemed interesting.

From  Cusick and Flahive:  appears you want Rogers (1970)  and. Bumby (1973) . C+F page 73, Thm 3, the set of your numbers has Haussdorff  dimension between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$

I see, Rogers is C. A. Rogers (1970)   Haussdorff Measures. Bumby (1973)   is in conference proceedings, (Editor Charles Osgood) The Markov spectrum. Pages 25-58

I think this does answer my question, thought I was right to mention my modest experience because this is well above what I can understand, but thank you for the answer.

@nnabahi  it is also in Khinchin's little book, more accessible. Theorem 29 on page 60 says the set of all numbers in the interval $(0,1)$ with bounded elements. Makes sense, my impression is that Khinchin invented the measure theory of continued fractions.  https://archive.org/details/khinchin-continued-fractions

Useful searches: "The fractional dimensional theory of continued fractions" (title of Irving John Good's well known 1941 paper) and Jarnik + "Hausdorff dimension" + "continued fraction".

Thank you very much! I'm going to take the summer to work through Khinchin's book before delving into anything deeper, this was very helpful!

I also recommend some Number Theory, especially how continued fractions and the Pell equation fit together. Here is a brief presentation https://ia804708.us.archive.org/33/items/flooved3516/flooved3516.pdf    Helpful: my impression is that students get a bit lost with all the subscripts. One type of cure: work through the business  with Pell, write out actual fractions (convergents)

Pretty good example, the method that seems to be what Fermat  settled on.  Continued fraction for $\sqrt{13}.$  Notice that I display  no subscripts.
Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$
$$  \sqrt { 13} = 3 +     \frac{  \sqrt {13} - 3 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {13} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 3 }{4 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 1 }{4 } $$
$$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {13} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 1 }{3 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 2 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {13} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 2 }{3 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 1 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {13} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 1 }{4 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 3 }{4 } $$
$$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {13} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 3 }{1 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 3 }{1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 119 }{ 33 }   & &   \frac{ 137 }{ 38 }   & &   \frac{ 256 }{ 71 }   & &   \frac{ 393 }{ 109 }   & &   \frac{ 649 }{ 180 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -4 & & 3 & & -3 & & 4 & & -1 & & 4 & & -3 & & 3 & & -4 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 13 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & 3^2 - 13 \cdot 1^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & 4^2 - 13 \cdot 1^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }   & 7^2 - 13 \cdot 2^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }   & 11^2 - 13 \cdot 3^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }   & 18^2 - 13 \cdot 5^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 119 }{ 33 }   & 119^2 - 13 \cdot 33^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 137 }{ 38 }   & 137^2 - 13 \cdot 38^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 256 }{ 71 }   & 256^2 - 13 \cdot 71^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 393 }{ 109 }   & 393^2 - 13 \cdot 109^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 649 }{ 180 }   & 649^2 - 13 \cdot 180^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

I'm sorry I don't see how this answers my question. (because otherwise your comments have been very spot on)

@nnabahi  it is just an example of continued fractions and the Pell equation.  As I commented, I think a little exposure to concrete  continued fractions, all the numbers filled in, is likely to help your understanding. Up to you.
